# SQLAlchemy sort by foreign column through hybrid property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a universal method of building queries for various models based on input from the frontend. Some queries require filter or sort on child table columns.
So I decided to have such columns as hybrid properties in master model:

```
class PurchaseOrder(db.Model, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'purchase_orders'

    ''' Represents purchase order '''
    id = Column(String(23), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    vendor_po_id = Column(String(12))
    suborder_id = Column(String(20), ForeignKey('suborders.id'), nullable=False)
    suborder = relationship('Suborder', foreign_keys=[suborder_id], lazy='joined')

    @hybrid_property
    def purchase_date(self):
        return self.suborder.buyout_date

    @purchase_date.expression
    def purchase_date(cls):
        return Suborder.buyout_date
```

So, I build a query and final clase looks like this:

```
query = query.order_by(PurchaseOrder.purchase_date)
```

In this case I expect that final query would be something like:

```
SELECT purchase_orders.*, suborders.* 
FROM purchase_orders JOIN suborders ON purchase_orders.suborder_id = suborders.id 
ORDER BY suborders.buyout_date
```

However what I've got is (columns are reduced):

```
SELECT purchase_orders.*, suborders_1.* 
FROM 
    purchase_orders 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN suborders AS suborders_1 ON suborders_1.id = purchase_orders.suborder_id 
ORDER BY suborders.buyout_date
```

Naturally I'm getting an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'suborders.buyout_date' in 'order clause'")
```

So the question - how do I do it right?